# Netty HTTP client download zip file

Tags: netty, nio

I'm writing Netty client which downloads one specific large file from one specific server using one specific url (`https://myserver.com/aaa.zip`) over HTTPS and saves it on disk.

I haven't found any example for HTTP client getting binary response, so digging some documentation this is what I got:

I'm using Netty 4.0.15

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
    SSLEngine engine =
            SecureSslContextFactory.getClientContext().createSSLEngine();
        engine.setUseClientMode(true);

    pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
    pipeline.addLast("codec",new HttpClientCodec());
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpWebClientHandler());
```

and my Handler looks like this:

```
public class HttpWebClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpObject> {

    File file = new File("aaa.zip");
        int written = 0;

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpObject msg)
            throws Exception {

        if (msg instanceof HttpContent){
            HttpContent content = (HttpContent) msg;
            int currentlyWritten = 0;
            ByteBuf byteBuf = content.content();        
             FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
             FileChannel localfileChannel = outputStream.getChannel();
             try{
             ByteBuffer byteBuffer = byteBuf.nioBuffer();
             currentlyWritten += localfileChannel.write(byteBuffer,written);
             written+=currentlyWritten;
                byteBuf.readerIndex(byteBuf.readerIndex() + currentlyWritten);
                localfileChannel.force(false);
            }finally{
                localfileChannel.close();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My file is downloaded and have the same ammount of bytes as original one, but file is corrupted and has wrong checksum.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpObjectDecoder` will possibly produce more than one `HttpContent` for a single HTTP response.  You create a new `FileOutputStream` on every `HttpContent`, so you will have only the last part of the response in the file.

To fix the problem:

- Open the file on `HttpRequest`
- Write the content of all `HttpContent`s
- Close the file on `LastHttpContent`.